# UILabel not showing in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UILabel withing a UICollectionViewCell object.

```
@interface TideDataTableCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* dayString;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dayLabel;

@end
```

The label is synthesized in the m file for the cell object. When I try to assign the text property though, the label object is always null. Even creating a new label and assigning it to the cell dayLabel does not work! The code below is just the straight assignment to the label as nothing seems to work...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Main Tide Data Table Cell";

    TideDataTableCell* tideDayDataCell = [self.tideDataTable dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tidalDate* tideDate = self.tidalDates[indexPath.row];
    self.tideDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tideDayDataCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tideDayDataCell.dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tideDayDataCell.dayLabel.text = tideDate.dateString;
    return tideDayDataCell;
}
```

Why does this not work?! I have checked that the label in the UICollectionViewCell is connected to the dayLabel in the cells h file (above)

Comment: Have you tried making dayLabel strong or retain? May be it is getting released before reusing cell as it is weak property.

Comment: Hi there... I have just tried making it strong and retain - but it still doesn't work...

Comment: OK... I have made some progress... I must have done it wrong before - I have created a new label and assigned it to the dayLabel property. The label - although it is no longer null still does not display in the uicollectionview

Comment: All sorted - I had followed a tutorial and forgot to comment out a line in viewDidLoad... Duh!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your cell on the viewDidLoad of TideDataTableCell like this:

```
UINib *cellNibName = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"cellNibName" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNibName forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

Then, at cellForItemAtIndexPath you have to get the cell and use it:

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    TideDataTableCell* tideDayDataCell = [self.tideDataTable dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    tidalDate* tideDate = self.tidalDates[indexPath.row];
    self.tideDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tideDayDataCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tideDayDataCell.dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tideDayDataCell.dayLabel.text = tideDate.dateString;
    return tideDayDataCell;
}
```

Don't forget to set the reuse identifier in the xib file.